# Warning: sqlsrv_has_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given (using inner join)

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, join

Necesito ayuda con esto, no me encontré con ninguna sorpresa hasta que tuve que realizar un **inner join** es primera vez que utilizo uno con php tal vez mi sintaxis esta incorrecta.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<?php include "lib/metodosbd.php";?>
<title>Consultar Guias</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body>
<header>
<div class="div-header">
  <section class="main row">
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
        <img src="img/OXblanco.png" width="320" height="107" >
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-11 col-sm-11 col-md-11 col-lg-11">
      </div>
   </section> 
  </div> 
</header>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Consultar guias</h2>

     <section class="main row" >
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
         <form  method="get" >
             <input name="folio" type="text"  id="folio" placeholder="Folio"             
/>
             <button type="submit" name="btn-guia" id="btn-guia">Consultar</button>
         </form>

         <?php
              if(isset($_GET['btn-guia'])){
                  consulta_guia();
              }

          ?>
       </div>


    </section>    
</div>  
 <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Aquí metodosbd.php

```
     <head>
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">

    </head>
    <?php
    include "conexion.php";

    function consulta_guia(){
        $con=conectar();

        $n_guia=$_GET['folio'];


    $stmtS="SELECT     iw_gmovi.Tipo, iw_gsaen.Folio, iw_gmovi.CodProd, iw_gmovi.CodBode, iw_gmovi.CantIngresada, iw_gmovi.CantDespachada, iw_gsaen.Estado FROM iw_gmovi INNER JOIN iw_gsaen ON     iw_gmovi.'Tipo' = iw_gsaen.'Tipo' AND iw_gmovi.NroInt = iw_gsaen.NroInt WHERE (iw_gmovi.Tipo IN ('s', 'e'))";

    $queryS=sqlsrv_query($con,$stmtS);

    if(sqlsrv_has_rows($queryS)){<-- aqui el error
    ?> 

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 ">
    <table align="center" style="margin:auto auto auto auto;" class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
        <tr >
            <td>Estado</td>
            <td>N° Guia</td>
            <td>Bodega</td>
            <td>Codigo producto</td>
            <td>Descripcion producto</td>
            <td>Cantidad entrada</td>
            <td>Cantidad salia</td>
            <td>Diferencias</td>
        </tr>
    <?php



        $i=0;

        while($fila=sqlsrv_fetch_array($queryS)){

            $EST=$fila['iw_gmovi.Tipo'];
            $N_GUI=$fila['iw_gmovi.NroInt'];
            $BOD=$fila['iw_gmovi.CodBode'];
            $COD_PORD=$fila['iw_gmovi.CodProd'];
            $DES_PROD=$fila['iw_gmovi.DetProd'];
            $CANT_SAL=$fila['iw_gmovi.CantDespachada'];
            $CANT_ENT=$fila['iw_gmovi.CantIngresada'];
            $DIF=$CANT_ENT['iw_gmovi.CantIngresada'] - $CANT_SAL['iw_gmovi.CantDespachada'];
            $i++;

        ?>
        <tr align="center" valign="middle" >
        <td ><?php echo $EST; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $BOD; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $COD_PORD; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $DES_PROD; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $CANT_SAL; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $DES_PROD; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $DIF; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </table>
        </div>
        <?php }else{
        ?><div class="alert-false" role="alert">ERROR: La guia no existe <br /> <?php  print_r( sqlsrv_errors())?> </div><?php
    }
    }

    ?>
```

Cabe mencionar que probé el programa ejecutando un selec * from iw_gmovi y logre imprimir el campo iw_gmovi.Tipo solo para saber si mi programa funcionaba ademas estos campos son de tipo varchar.

Comment: Tienes error de sintaxis aquí: `iw_gmovi.'Tipo' = iw_gsaen.'Tipo'` y en todo lo que se le parezca. La columna `Tipo` no tiene que llevar comillas ahí, debes escribirlo así: `iw_gmovi.Tipo = iw_gsaen.Tipo` ... revisa el resto de la consulta, es larga, el código no está identado y da pereza desplazarse tanto hacia la derecha. :-)

Comment: corregí la consulta


 $stmtS="SELECT     iw_gmovi.Tipo, iw_gsaen.Folio, iw_gmovi.CodProd, iw_gmovi.CodBode, iw_gmovi.CantIngresada, 
  iw_gmovi.CantDespachada, iw_gsaen.Estado FROM iw_gmovi INNER JOIN iw_gsaen ON  iw_gmovi.'Tipo' = iw_gsaen.Tipo 
  AND iw_gmovi.NroInt = iw_gsaen.NroInt WHERE (iw_gmovi.Tipo IN ('s', 'e'))";

Comment: Sigo viendo comillas simples por aquí: `iw_gmovi.'Tipo' `

Comment: Encontré la solución ademas del error de las comillas simples, me di cuenta de que la consulta estaba mal, esto lo comprobé pegando la consulta en sql server. Hacer esto me ayudo bastante ya que el mensaje era un poco mas especifico